# Regex in grep for files containing A,B,C... but not Z

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Spent a few hours trying to answer this question on my own using partial answers to this question; so I apologize if this has already been answered, but combining the partial solutions I could find to properly perform this search seems to be beyond me.

**What I'm trying to do:** Search through a directory for files containing multiple unique strings in any order, anywhere in the file, but not containing another certain string anywhere in the file.

Here's the search I have so far:

```
pcregrep -riM '^(?=.*uniquestringA)(?=.*uniquestringB)(?=.*uniquestringC)(?=.*uniquestringD)(?=.*uniquestringE).*$' . 
| xargs grep -Li 'uniquestringZ'
```

I realize that this is horribly, horribly wrong as I can't even seem to get the multi-line search to work while ignoring the order the strings appear.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it requires a lot of grep invocations, you can just write it out with `find` and `grep` in a simple and POSIX compliant way:

```
find . -type f \
  -exec grep -q "stringA" {} \; \
  -exec grep -q "stringB" {} \; \
  -exec grep -q "stringC" {} \; \
  -exec grep -q "stringD" {} \; \
  ! -exec grep -q "stringZ" {} \; \
  -print  # or whatever to do with matches
```

Comment: A bit slow, but I didn't imagine I'd find a blazing fast solution to this, works beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

If your grep has lookaheads, you should be able to do

```
^(?!.*Z)(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C)(.*)$
```

[See it work](http://regex101.com/r/sE4vK3/1)

With this file:

```
$ cat /tmp/grep_tgt.txt
A,B,C      # should match
A,B,C,D    # should match
A,C,D      # no match, lacking upper b
A,B,C,Z    # no match, has upper z
```

You can use perl one liner:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /^(?!.*Z)(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C)(.*)$/' /tmp/grep_tgt.txt
A,B,C      # should match
A,B,C,D    # should match
```

With file names:

```
$ find . -type f
./.DS_Store
./A-B-C
./A-B-C-Z
./A-C-D
./sub/A-B-C-D
```

You can filter the file names with perl:

```
$ find . -type f | perl -ne 'print if /^(?!.*Z)(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C)(.*)$/'
./A-B-C
./sub/A-B-C-D
```

If you want to read the file contents to test for a pattern (like grep), you can do:

```
$ find . -type f | xargs perl -ne 'print "$ARGV: $&\n" if /^
(?!.*Z)(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C)(.*)$/'
./1.txt: A B C     # should match
./2.txt: A,B,C,D    # should match
```

where I put four files in a directory (1.txt .. 4.txt) with the text inside of 1.txt and 2.txt that match.

Comment: ^(?!.*Z)(?=.*A)(.*)$ seems to work fine for me, but as soon as I add add a second term to include the search returns nothing, even if I simply search ^(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(.*)$ this is using pcregrep, which I have used to successfully perform negative lookaheads before, at least.

Comment: I can, and I tried your suggested search, but I feel like that perl is only being run on the file name itself not the contents? I only get results if I cut it down to a single term (?!.*Z) or (?=.*A) but never more than one. I know the file contents have more than one of these strings, but the names only have one.

Comment: O -- yes, I thought you DID only want it on the file names.  You can use the same kind of perl, but just use `xargs` to invoke perl. You can use perl and a very souped up grep. Try it.

Comment: @thatotherguy's answer ended up working out but thank you as well, I hadn't considered using perl to filter the results, and will have to give this a try in the future to see if I can get faster results.